# ZeroMQ - subscriber is able to receive data from 1st publisher but does not receive from 2nd publisher which is up after a few loops

Tags: c++, zeromq, publisher, subscriber

In following code. Publisher thread publish 5 messages then again new publisher socket is supposed to send data to subscriber but subscriber is in `while(1)` loop for `recv()` and never get message from 2nd publisher. How subscriber can connect to publisher 2 with some exception handling that subscriber 2 is trying to connect.

I tried with `XPUB/XSUB`, `PUSH/PULL` and also `ZMQ_HEARTBEAT` but no exception is caught. Also tried with `"inproc://#1"` instead of `"tcp://127.0.0.1:5555"`. Nothing worked

```
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "zmq.hpp"
#include <string>
#include <strings.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
void PublisherThread(zmq::context_t* ctx){
    try{
        std::cout << "PublisherThread: " << std::endl;
        zmq::socket_t publisher(*ctx, ZMQ_PUB);
        publisher.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:5555");
        int counter = 0;
        while (true){
            try{
                publisher.send(zmq::str_buffer("A"), zmq::send_flags::sndmore);
                publisher.send(zmq::str_buffer("Message in A envelope\n"));
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(2000));
                publisher.send(zmq::str_buffer("B"), zmq::send_flags::sndmore);
                publisher.send(zmq::str_buffer("Message in B envelope\n"));
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(2000));
                publisher.send(zmq::str_buffer("C"), zmq::send_flags::sndmore);
                publisher.send(zmq::str_buffer("Message in C envelope\n"));
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(2000));
                if(counter == 5){
                    publisher.close();
                    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(2000));
                    counter = 0;
                    break;
                }
                else{
                    counter++;
                }
            }
            catch(const zmq::error_t& ze){
                std::cout<<"PublisherThread: catch 2:"<<ze.what()<<std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
    catch(const zmq::error_t& ze){
        std::cout<<"PublisherThread: catch 1:"<<ze.what()<<std::endl;
    }
    try{
        zmq::socket_t publisher2(*ctx, ZMQ_PUB);
        publisher2.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:5555");
        int counter = 0;
        while (true){
            try{
            //  Write three messages, each with an envelope and content
            publisher2.send(zmq::str_buffer("A"), zmq::send_flags::sndmore);
                publisher2.send(zmq::str_buffer("Message in A envelope\n"));
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(2000));
                publisher2.send(zmq::str_buffer("B"), zmq::send_flags::sndmore);
                publisher2.send(zmq::str_buffer("Message in B envelope\n"));
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(2000));
                publisher2.send(zmq::str_buffer("C"), zmq::send_flags::sndmore);
                publisher2.send(zmq::str_buffer("Message in C envelope\n"));
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(2000));
                if(counter == 50){
                    publisher2.close();
                    break;
                }
                else{
                    counter++;
                }
            }
            catch(const zmq::error_t& ze){
                std::cout<<"PublisherThread: catch 4:"<<ze.what()<<std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
    catch(const zmq::error_t& ze){
        std::cout<<"PublisherThread: catch 3:"<<ze.what()<<std::endl;
    }
    std::cout<<"PublisherThread: exiting:"<<std::endl;
void SubscriberThread1(zmq::context_t* ctx){
    std::cout<< "SubscriberThread1: " << std::endl;
    zmq::socket_t subscriber(*ctx, ZMQ_SUB);
    subscriber.setsockopt(ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, "A", 1);
    subscriber.setsockopt(ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, "B", 1);
    subscriber.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:5555");
    while (1){
        try{
            zmq::message_t address;
            zmq::recv_result_t result = subscriber.recv(address);
            //  Read message contents
            zmq::message_t contents;
            result = subscriber.recv(contents);
            std::cout<< "Thread2: "<< std::string(static_cast<char*>(contents.data()), contents.size())<< std::endl;
        }
        catch(const zmq::error_t& ze){
            std::cout<<"subscriber catch error:"<<ze.what()<<std::endl;
        }
    }
}
int main(){
    zmq::context_t* zmq_ctx = new zmq::context_t();
    std::thread thread1(PublisherThread, zmq_ctx);
    std::thread thread2(SubscriberThread1, zmq_ctx);
    thread1.join();
    thread2.join();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> **Q :**
> *<sub>" How subscriber can connect to publisher 2 with some exception handling that subscriber 2 is trying to connect. "</sub>*

**A :**
The as-is code does serially chain `{_a_try_scope_of_PUB_in_an_infinite_loop_}` only after which is `break`-broken or otherwise terminated and exited from, the same `thread1`-code follows to the other one, having left the former, now entering `{_a_try_scope_of_PUB2_again_into_another_infinite_loop_}`.

Just this fact self-explains, why a subscriber-side SUB-end never receives a single message from the second publisher, if a ZeroMQ configuration property addressed as `ZMQ_LINGER` silently blocks the progress of closing a first `PUB`-archetype socket instance, still owned by the `publisher` ( this `LINGER`-attribute was in some native-API versions documented to have a default value such that the release will never happen, if undelivered messages were still present inside the internal queue, in some cases even blocking the IP:PORT "beyond" a code exit, leaving us only to use a hardware reboot as a strategy of last resort to release a such hanging `Context()`-instance from infinite occupation of that port - was in python code under pyzmq-language wrapper for ZeroMQ native-API DLL, all run in Windows. Definitely not an experience one would like to have a single more time. So in newer versions of native-API, the `LINGER` started to have another, non-infinite waiting default value - so version dependence has to be best overcome with explicit setting the `LINGER` property, right after the socket-instance gets created - a sign of good engineering practice ).

Looking onto an option to let each one work from a pair of autonomous threads - a `threadP1` + another `PUB` inside a `threadP2` :

```
int main(){
    zmq::context_t* zmq_ctx = new zmq::context_t();

    std::thread threadP1( PubThread1, zmq_ctx );
    std::thread threadP2( PubThread2, zmq_ctx );

    std::thread threadS1( SubThread1, zmq_ctx );

    threadP1.join();
    threadP2.join();
    threadS1.join();
}
```

- here we have indeed both of the `PUB`-sides independently entering into their own `try{...}`-scope and trying to proceed into there present infinite `while(){...}`-loop ( ignoring the hidden `break`-branch there for the moment ), yet with a new problem here ...

```
#define TAKE_A_NAP std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::milliseconds( 2000 ) )

void PubThread1( zmq::context_t* ctx ){
    try{
                                 std::cout << "PubThread1: " << std::endl;
        zmq::socket_t publisher( *ctx, ZMQ_PUB );
     // publisher.setsockopt(          ZMQ_LINGER, 0 );   // property settings
        publisher.bind( "tcp://127.0.0.1:5555" );         // resource .bind()

        int counter = 0;
        while ( true ){
            try{
                publisher.send( zmq::str_buffer( "A" ), 
                                zmq::send_flags::sndmore );
                publisher.send( zmq::str_buffer( "Msg in envelope A from PUB1\n" ) );
                                TAKE_A_NAP;
                publisher.send( zmq::str_buffer( "B" ),
                                zmq::send_flags::sndmore );
                publisher.send( zmq::str_buffer( "Msg in envelope B from PUB1\n" ) );
                                TAKE_A_NAP;
                publisher.send( zmq::str_buffer( "C" ),
                                zmq::send_flags::sndmore );
                publisher.send( zmq::str_buffer( "Msg in envelope C from PUB1\n" ) );
                                
                if ( counter > 4 ){
                     counter = 0;
                     publisher.close();
                                TAKE_A_NAP;
                     break;
                }
            }
            catch( const zmq::error_t& ze ){
                                std::cout << "PubThread1: catch 2:"<<ze.what()<<std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
    catch( const zmq::error_t& ze ){
                                std::cout << "PubThread1: catch 1:"<<ze.what()<<std::endl;
          /*    publisher.close(); /* a fair place
                                          to dismantle all resources here
                                          to avoid a hanging instance ALAP */
    }
```

We need to somehow solve a new, only now appearing, colliding attempts to `.bind()`-acquire one and the same resource twice, which for obvious reasons cannot happen - so the "slower" of the pair will fail to also `.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:5555")` onto an already occupied *`ADDRESS:PORT`*-resource, the faster one has already managed to acquire and use.

Using different, non-colliding *`ADDRESS:PORT`* resources is one way, using a reversed bind/connect scenario is the other.

There the `SUB.bind()`-s and both of the `{ PUB1 | PUB2 }.connect()` to a single, publicly known `SUB`-AccessPoint's *`ADDRESS:PORT`* used for the `SUB`-side.

Initial ZeroMQ versions were using `SUB`-side topic-filtering, meaning all messages were delivered "across"-network to all `SUB`-s, where the topic-filter was applied after "network"-side delivery, to decide, if a particular match was found, dropping a message if not. More recent versions ( having larger RAMs and multi-core CPUs ) started to process topic-filtering ( and also all the subscription-management ) on the `PUB`-side. This increases the processing & RAM overheads on the `PUB`-side, and may run us into problems, what happens if properly subscribed to `PUB1` gets closed ( throwing away all subscription-management it carried on ) and leaving us in doubts, if newly delivered `PUB2`, once properly `.bind()`, occupying the same *`ADDRESS:PORT`* location, will somehow receive the subscription-requests repeated from a `SUB`-side, in the newer API mode. Details & version changes indeed matter here. Best to walk on the safer side - so the old assembler practitioners' `#ASSUME NOTHING` directive serves best if obeyed here )

Last, but not least, a handy notice. The `PUB/SUB`-archetype works with topic filtering in such a way, that does not require going into multipart-message composition's complexities. The topic-filter is a pure left-to-right ASCII-matching, so using the filter simply checks left-to-right the beginning of the message, be it a multipart-message composed of `{ "A" | "...whatever.text.here..." }` or a plain-message `"A...whatever..."`, `"ABC...whaterver..."`, `"B884884848484848484..."`, `"C<lf><lf><0xD0D0><cr>"` and likes - simplicity helps performance and was always a part of the Zen-of-Zero.

Comment: From list of good comments, what i can understand is that you are saying that 2 pubs can not acquire same resource i.e. Address:Port but i remember from old socket programming that in IS_FDSET kind of scenario, after 1 client is gone then 2nd can connect. Actually i tried with unbind() call also but that didn't work. This example is just simple among complex program where certain algo result is published by many algo apps in background so can't create N number of bind ports for subscriber.

Comment: Well, ZeroMQ Scalable Formal Communication Pattern Archetypes (in spite of being called sockets for brevity) are by far not just sockets. If interested in going deeper into ZeroMQ infrastructure, perhaps a fast crash course into this may help you get the key concepts first in a few minutes - take a few of the first items from https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a3666197%20%5bzeromq%5d and can scan deeper and deeper given the foundations are got first & firm. Anyway, ZeroMQ will help you a lot on low-level details, while having been tuned for ultimate performance, minimum latency

Comment: For ultimate clarity, I did say, that relying on resource being released ( for another use ) is a risky assumption in [tag:distributed-system] given no explicit control of ZMQ_LINGER was present and many things may turn wreck havoc, if we forget to take into account (now distributed-)blocking, actual durations (outside of our code scope of cotnrol) and costs-of-instantiations. ZeroMQ infrastructure uses Context()-engines for a lot of work under the hood, so a .bind() / .unbind() / .bind()-again strategy is a sort of brute in this. We may use a manyIn-2-oneOut proxy-collector, who remains bound

Comment: I really appreciate for taking out some time and enlightenment in your response. I will surely look at crash course as suggested. Thanx in advance if you can please share any link of manyIn-2-oneOut proxy-collector example in C++.

Comment: I think that Poller() is the right approach to solve this kind of problem. Perhaps this is the one you were pointing at with manyIn-2-oneOut. right?

Comment: Great to read how high appreciation you have. StackOverflow strongly discourages from creeping the original problem definition. Feel free to open any new question(s) as you feel you need MCVE-based problem solution advice & shall +1 useful & accept best answers previously sponsored by actively contributing Community members and delivered to you, that's fair, isn't it? Adding this & that & also what about something else is **simply not the way StackOverflow works**. Be fair & best comply with the Community Netiquette ( which all users claimed to do comply with, during the signup, didn't we? )

Comment: User3666197 - please refrain from adding copy+paste conversational asides to your posts. You have several, one of which is "Welcome to the zeromq lands of Zen-of-Zero" and slight variations thereof. The other one is convoluted syntactical mess of "In case one has never worked with ZeroMQ, one may here enjoy to first look at "ZeroMQ Principles in less than Five Seconds" before diving into further details". Stack Overflow (again - two words) is not a chatroom. Spelling, grammar, and formatting, should be readable and succinct.

Comment: If you don't like an edit then - in your case specifically - I would recommend flagging for a moderator. With that in mind, do try to avoid making your edit messages injurious. We're just aiming for quality here, and no-one is being censored. (Feel free to send me a PM if you want to discuss the philosophies of censorship - I find the topic of state power interesting, but it is not very relevant here).